# SQL Server 2008: what happened if identity oversteps a maximal value of int?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity, identity-column

Imagine we have a table:

```
create table MYTABLE (
 id int IDENTITY(1,1)
,name varchar(10)
)
```

We have to insert a lot of rows into the table.

Does anybody know what will happen when a generated identity  value oversteps a maximal integer value (2^63-1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error will occur and the insert will be lost.

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
>   Arithmetic overflow occurred.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a documentation.

Answer (score 5):

An example

```
create table dbo.MYTABLE (
 id tinyint IDENTITY(254,1)
,name varchar(10)
)
GO
INSERT dbo.MYTABLE (name) VALUES ('row 254')
GO
INSERT dbo.MYTABLE (name) VALUES ('row 255')
GO
INSERT dbo.MYTABLE (name) VALUES ('broke')
GO
```

gives

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type tinyint.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily test this with a very small identity column, like `decimal(1,0)`:

```
create table IdentityOverflow (id decimal(1,0) identity)
while 1=1
    insert IdentityOverflow default values
```

Like Oded says, this prints:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type decimal.
```

This holds for even the largest of integers:

```
create table IdentityOverflow (
    id decimal(38,0) identity(1,10000000000000000000000000000000000000))
while 1=1
    insert IdentityOverflow default values
```